# Convert time string to local time

Tags: javascript, github, timezone

Using the Github API I get times which look like this "2013-11-05T21:41:37Z", I think the 'Z' refers to zulu time i.e. UTC. What is the easiest way to convert this time to local time, using javascript (taking into account summer time changes)?

Comment: [moment](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Google....whole sites devoted to time

Comment: @charlietfl that's the problem, time is a complex subject, there is too much information, it's hard to find answers to my specific issue

Comment: @josh3736 exactly what I needed, please write it up as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: @charlietfl there is a site devoted to everything, finding it is the problem. If google was the answer there would be no need for SO.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[moment](http://momentjs.com/) is a great library for dealing with dates and times.

It supports parsing ISO date times.

Answer (score 2):

`new Date('2013-11-05T21:41:37Z')` returns the user's computer's set timezone. It automatically converts it to local time for you.

Comment: Not all browsers support passing an ISO date string to the `Date` constructor.

Comment: ...see [this chart](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html) for compatibility details.